# What is the best way to handle DNS and failover management for a subdomain website when I don't have control of the domain?

Tags: domain, load-balancing, subdomain, failover, cloudflare

Updating DNS for this subdomain would take hours or days, but we'd like to be able to set up a reliable auto-failover mechanism that I think would require faster DNS changes. What is best practice for this type of arrangement?

Comment: Lower the TTL, and have then CNAME the subdomain at a record you control?

Comment: Is it possible to do this and use Cloudflare's features for the subdomain? I've heard of delegation as a potential solution. Ideally I could control the subdomain at Cloudflare directly.